# Нужно, чтобы ответ программа считала с точной 2 знака после запятой

Tags: java

У меня есть задание: Дана последовательность целых чисел из N
элементов. Найдите среднее арифметическое элементов последовательности, имеющих нечетное значение. Выведите среднее арифметическое элементов последовательности, имеющих нечетное значение. Ответ выведите с точностью 2 знака после запятой. Если в последовательности нет нечётных элементов, выведите "NO".
Я написал код, но ответ получается без остатка после деления, только целая часть. Как сделать так, чтобы программа считала ответ вместе с остатком?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N = s.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[N];

        for (N = 0; N <array.length; N++){
            array[N] = s.nextInt();
        }

        int sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        float result;

        for (N = 0; N <array.length; N++){
            if (array[N]%2!=0){
                sum += array[N];
                i++;
            }
        }
        result = (sum/i);
        if(i > 0)
            System.out.print(result);
        else
            System.out.print("NO");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно объявить `float sum = 0;` вместо `int sum = 0;` (при целочисленных sum и i производится целочисленное же деление)
2. `result = sum / i;` нужно перенести внутрь `if (i > 0)` во избежание деления на 0
3. Вывести отформатированное число можно с помощью `System.out.printf("%.2f", result);`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N = s.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[N];

        for (N = 0; N < array.length; N++) {
            array[N] = s.nextInt();
        }

        float sum = 0;
        int i = 0;
        float result;

        for (N = 0; N < array.length; N++) {
            if (array[N] % 2 != 0) {
                sum += array[N];
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            result = sum / i;
            System.out.printf("%.2f", result);
        } else
            System.out.print("NO");
    }
}
```

```
3
3
3
5
3,67
```

Comment: Спасибо! Уже сам решил с помощью System.out.printf. Но всё равно спасибо что ответили